# How to import google snappy to eclipse C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, snappy

I have an eclipse C++ project and downloaded the google snappy project files (http://google.github.io/snappy/) over into eclipse.

Once I attempt to compile, I receive an error stating:

```
  fatal error: snappy-stubs-public.h: No such file or directory...
```

This file doesn't exist, but when I go into the file snappy-stats-public.h.in it says that the file (missing) will be generated at configure time. Is there something I am missing to get this working?

Comment: It seems to me like you may be meant to use your terminal and run `./autogen.sh` followed by `./configure` from the folder where you extracted Snappy.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Although I followed some slightly different steps, it worked in the end. Do you know how I can now copy this into eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

i solve this by re-executing cmake, the file generates again